# Modeling XML Data for a C# Application

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm missing a concept with regards to modeling data in XML. Consider the following XML which is going to hold some configuration data for an application I'm writing.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DateGuessConfigValues>
  <Players>
    <Player Id="1">
      <Name>Yusnier Viera</Name>
      <Country>Cuba</Country>
    </Player>
    <Player Id="2">
      <Name>Ron White</Name>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Player>    
  </Players>
  <Centuries>
    <Century>1900</Century>
    <Century>2000</Century>
  </Centuries>
</DateGuessConfigValues>
```

I'm storing this XML in a file named "DateGuessConfig.xml" and then running the following program...

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        String strPath = @"C:\XMLExample\DateGuessConfig.xml";
        XElement xEle = XElement.Load(strPath);    
        var query = xEle.Descendants("Centuries").ToList();    
        foreach (var c in query)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(c.Element("Century").Value);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press <enter> to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I expect my result to be...

1900

2000

However I'm only getting

1900

Am I modeling the data incorrectly? should I use an attribute instead of inner text?

Comment: How many entries are in `query`? What does [`XElement.Element(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xcontainer.element(v=vs.110).aspx) return when there are multiple elements? Does `XElement` have a method that lets you select _multiple_ child elements, by name? (Hint: [it does](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be simplified to just use the [`Descendants`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813(v=vs.110).aspx) call:

```
foreach (var c in xEle.Descendants("Century"))
{
   Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
}
```

This is slightly different than MikeH's answer which still runs the query

Answer (score 2):

`query` in your example has only one element: The `Centuries` node.  You need to access its descendants.  So, in your example it went through the loop once and retrieved the first `Century` value.

Try replacing your `foreach` with this:

```
 foreach (var c in query.Descendants("Century"))
      {
        Console.WriteLine(c.Value);
      }
```

Comment: That is the answer. I was over complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use a DataTable instead.  See code below.  It will write with schema so integers don't have to be parsed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data;


namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet("DateGuessConfigValues");
            DataTable playerTable = new DataTable("Players");
            ds.Tables.Add(playerTable);
            DataTable centuriesTable = new DataTable("Centuries");
            ds.Tables.Add(centuriesTable);

            playerTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            playerTable.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            playerTable.Columns.Add("Country", typeof(string));

            playerTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {1, "Viera", "Cuba"});
            playerTable.Rows.Add(new object[] {2, "Ron White", "USA"});


            centuriesTable.Columns.Add("Century", typeof(int));

            centuriesTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1900});
            centuriesTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2000});

            ds.WriteXml("Filename", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

            ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml("Filename");
        }
    }


}

​
```